# C# printing and skipping a certain number of characters

Tags: c#, .net, character, skip

Ok, here's the problem that I have: using C# I want to format a string by printing out a certain number of characters, then skipping a certain number of characters and then again print, skip.

For example: I want to print 3 characters by skipping the next 2.

So this:
ABCDEFGHIJKL

would become this:
ABCFGHKL

I have only made that it could skip every 2,3,4 and so on characters and I couldn't think of how to approach this further.

Here is so far what I have

```
string text;
    int print = 3;
    int skip = 2;

    StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"c:\test.txt");

    while ((text = file.Readtext()) != null)
    {
            string[] stringArray = new string[text.Length];
            char ch;

            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
            {
                ch = text[i];
                stringArray[i] = ch.ToString();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.Length; i+=skip)
            {
                Console.Write(stringArray[i]);
            }
}
```

Thanks.

---

Thank you guys for various great solutions, I really appreciate your help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
int take = 3;
int skip = 2;
string s = "ABCDEFGHIJKL";

var newstr = String.Join("", s.Where((c,i) => i % (skip + take) < take));
```

---

**EDIT**

Here are my test results....

```
int take = 3;
int skip = 2;

string s = String.Join("",Enumerable.Repeat("0123456789", 200));

var t1 = Measure(10000, () => { var newstr = String.Join("", s.Where((c, i) => i % (skip + take) < take)); });
var t2 = Measure(10000, () => { var newstr = new string(s.Where((c, i) => i % (skip + take) < take).ToArray()); });
var t3 = Measure(10000, () => { var newstr = GetString(s, take, skip); });


long Measure(int n,Action action)
{
    action(); //JIT???
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        action();
    }
    return sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
1665 ms. (String.Join)
1154 ms. (new string())
7457 ms. (Sayse's GetString)
```

---

**EDIT 2**

Modifying Sayse's answer as below gives the fastest result among the codes i tested. (**311** ms)

```
 public string GetString(string s, int substringLen, int skipCount)
{
    StringBuilder newString = new StringBuilder(s.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i += skipCount)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < substringLen && i < s.Length; j++)
        {
            newString.Append(s[i++]);
        }
    }
    return newString.ToString();
}
```

Comment: you can simply use `s.Where((_,i) => i % (skip + take) < take)` inside `Join`

Comment: I hope you don't mind but I added benchmarking to my answer.. It looks like a fair test to me, thought I would check if you see errors in it that makes it unfair to your answer?

Comment: @Sayse, No problem I added my own tests too.

Answer (score 1):

I like I4V's answer more but heres one way to achieve this

```
    public string GetString(string s, int substringLen, int skipCount)
    {
        string newString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i += skipCount)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < substringLen && i < s.Length; j++)
            {
                newString += s[i++];
            }
        }
        return newString;
    }
```

**Edit** Benchmark stated my way was faster

```
        var newStr2 = new Program().GetString(a, take, skip);
        var newstr = String.Join("", a.Where((c, i) => i % (skip + take) < take));

        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            newStr2 = new Program().GetString(a, take, skip);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("my way: " + sw.Elapsed.ToString());

        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            newstr = String.Join("", a.Where((c, iv) => iv % (skip + take) < take));
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("I4V way: " + sw.Elapsed.ToString());
```

> Output
>
> my way: 00:00:00.7634927
>
> I4V way: 00:00:01.0183307

Comment: Sayse, I see *same* results on my machine(1836(mine) vs 1865 ms). The only difference that i invoke each method once(to avoid JIT time) before making measurements. And if I test them with a 2000-bytes string my version seems to work 5 times faster.

Comment: Sayse, BTW my intention was not the performance while I was giving that answer.

Answer (score 0):

This how to do that.
I think this may be more clear if you are not familiar with Lambda expression

```
        int print = 3;
        int skip = 2;
        string str = "ABCDEFGHILKL";

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        string res = String.Empty;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < str.Length)
        {
            stringBuilder.Append(str.Substring(i, Math.Min(print, str.Length - i)));
            i += print + skip;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(stringBuilder.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  int print = 3;
  int skip = 2;

  Boolean isPrintState = true;
  int statePosition = 0;

  StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder();

  using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"c:\test.txt")) { 
    while (true) {
      int Ch = reader.Read();

      if (Ch < 0)
        break;

      statePosition += 1;

      if ((isPrintState && (statePosition > print)) || (!isPrintState && (statePosition > skip))) {
        statePosition = 1;
        isPrintState = !isPrintState;
      }

      if (isPrintState) 
        Sb.Append((Char) Ch);
    }
  }

  Console.Write(Sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Amidst so many good looking answer, mine might not be so sophisticated but I thought I would post it anyways. Simple logic.

```
var take = 3;
var skip = 2;

StringBuilder source = new StringBuilder("ABCDEFGHIJKL");            
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

while (source.Length > 0)
{
    if (source.Length >= take)
    {
        result.Append(source.ToString().Substring(0, take));
    }
    else
    {
        result.Append(source.ToString());
    }
    if (source.Length > skip + take)
    {
        source.Remove(0, skip + take);
    }
    else
        source.Clear();
}
```